# Modeling a gas nozzle

Tags: modeling

I'm building up this nozzle but can't get a clean look after sub-division.

I wonder what's wrong with the lines.

update:

here's how it looks after i deleted the inner faces.
i guess the lines are just not arranged in a right way? i'd appreciate if anyone can point something out thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe there's a inner faces, or overlapping vertices? If you don't find, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots just uploaded! thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Make the outer faces invisible so that you can see what happens inside your mesh, as you can see there are inner faces, delete them:

[image]

As for you new file, as you see if you enable the *Face Orientation* display option, you have inverted faces. In *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate:

[image]

Comment: thanks i deleted the inner face!! but the result still looks problematic after shade smooth.....

Comment: I've edited my answer, it's a problem of inverted normals  ;)

Comment: !amazing.. thank you so much knowledge checked!!<33